# Existe um iterator em bash equivalente ao enumerate do python?

Tags: linux, bash

É comum situações em que, para fazer a iteração, preciso não apenas dos elementos de uma lista, mas também de seus respectivos índices. No python, esse tipo de iteração é facilitada com o uso do iterator `enumerate`. Exemplo:

```py
for index, element in enumerate(["Walter", "Jesse","Skyler", "Gus"]):
    print("O personagem {} chama-se {}".format(index+1,element))
```

Retorna:

```
O personagem 1 chama-se Walter
O personagem 2 chama-se Jesse
O personagem 3 chama-se Skyler
O personagem 4 chama-se Gus
```

Em bash, eu consigo fazer a iteração normal, usando a syntaxe

```bsh
for VAR in Walter Jesse Skyler Gus
do
   echo "O nome do personagem é $VAR"
done
```

Mas não sei como faria para pegar o index da cada elemento. Existe um equivalente do `enumerate` nativo do bash?

Comment: Ah, só pra constar, no `enumerate` você pode definir o valor inicial usando o parâmetro `start`, assim não precisa somar 1 ao imprimir: https://ideone.com/U9bDGE

Comment: Não sabia disso. Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já agora mais uma variante:

```
i=0;  for a in Harry Ron Voldermort ; do echo "$((++i)): $a"; done
```

produzindo o esperado

```
1: Harry
2: Ron
3: Voldermort
```

Answer (score 7):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
pessoas=(Walter Jesse Skyler Gus)

for indice in "${!pessoas[@]}"
do
   echo "$indice = ${pessoas[$indice]}"
done
```

Saída:

```
0 = Walter
1 = Jesse
2 = Skyler
3 = Gus
```

### Explicações

[@]: Array indexado

!: Acesso ao indice

[Referência oficial clicando aqui](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays)

Comment: Legal. Era isso mesmo. Mas o que significam os símbolos @, $,{ ,} , etc ?

Comment: @Lucas Vou editar a pergunta e colocar o significado, junto com a referência oficial

Answer (score 5):

Até dá pra fazer, só não sei se é tão prático quanto simplesmente acessar os índices diretamente, como indicou a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/486949/112052).

Então vamos por partes. Primeiro partimos do seu array:

```
pessoas=(Walter Jesse Skyler Gus)
```

[Na documentação](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays) vemos que há a sintaxe `${pessoas[@]}` para obter os valores do array e `${!pessoas[@]}` para obter os índices. Mas se eu fizer apenas `echo "${pessoas[@]}"`, ele imprime os valores na mesma linha. Então eu faço:

```
echo "${pessoas[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n'
```

Para trocar os espaços por quebras de linha, assim cada um fica em uma linha. E por que eu fiz assim? Para poder usar o comando [`paste`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/paste):

```
paste <(echo "${!pessoas[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n') <(echo "${pessoas[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n')
```

Eu coloco cada comando `echo` (um para os índices, outro para os valores) dentro de `<( )`, que é chamado de [*process substitution*](https://superuser.com/q/1059781). De forma bem resumida, `paste` pega a saída desses comandos, linha a linha, e imprime a primeira linha de cada um deles, depois a segunda linha de cada um, e assim por diante.

A saída será:

```
0       Walter
1       Jesse
2       Skyler
3       Gus
```

Agora que eu já tenho os índices e os respectivos valores, basta lê-los em um *loop*:

```
pessoas=(Walter Jesse Skyler Gus)
paste <(echo "${!pessoas[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n') <(echo "${pessoas[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n') | while read indice valor
do
    echo "$indice=$valor"
done
```

Mas como eu já disse no início, é uma volta e tanto só para simular o `enumerate`. A solução da outra resposta me parece mais simples.

---

Vale lembrar que esta abordagem falha se um dos valores tiver espaço. Por exemplo, se for um array com 3 elementos:

```
pessoas=(Walter Jesse "Gus Fring")
```

Se eu usar o código acima, o `tr` irá substituir o espaço no terceiro elemento ("Gus Fring"), separando-o em 2 linhas.

Para evitar este problema, podemos trocar o `echo` por um `for` que imprime os elementos um por linha:

```
paste <(for i in "${!pessoas[@]}"; do echo $i ; done) <(for i in "${pessoas[@]}"; do echo $i ; done) | while ... # o restante é igual
```

Comment: Sensacional! Obrigado